Upgrading postgres version in django error
I'm trying to get postgres 14 (upgrading from 11) to work locally. Initially the docker file looked like:


 db:
    image: postgres-14.11
    environment:
      
    volumes:
     
    healthcheck:
      test:
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"



When running this ended up giving the following error:


find /usr -name postgis.control -->>DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/15/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.



So i did some research and tried to change my docker-compose to:


 db:
    image: postgis/postgis:14-3.4
    environment:
     
    volumes:
    
    healthcheck:
      test: 
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"



this instead gave me this error:


django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_extension_name_index"
DETAIL:  Key (extname)=(postgis) already exists.



which doesn't make sense to me .. not sure what's happening or what the fix for this should be
